# Remove duplicate empty lines in terminal in Node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, console

Not sure if this is possible, I would love to remove duplicate empty lines in the terminal in real-time

For example:

```
console.log('cat');
console.log('');
console.log('');
console.log('');
console.log('dog');
```

received:

```
cat



dog
```

expected:

```
cat

dog
```

Noticed that 2 duplicate empty lines are removed

I think a possible solution is that before printing a new empty line, read current stout, if the last item is an empty line, do not console.log this new empty line

Not sure how to do this in real-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cat` with `-s` or `--squeeze-blank` option.

Pipe the nodejs script output to cat -s,

```
node whatever.js | cat -s
```